# How to get a particular JSON element of an array?

Tags: javascript, lodash

There is an `array` of `JSON`s :

```
var a = [ {id:1, latlong:[...]} , {id:2, latlong:[...]} , ... ];
```

How to get the JSON element which key `id` equals 2 for example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes

Comment: Please read: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a single entry, there's the [`.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method:

```
const a = [ {id:1, latlong:[...]} , {id:2, latlong:[...]} , ... ];
const el = a.find((item) => item.id === 2);
console.log(el);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

```
var a = [ {id:1, latlong:[...]} , {id:2, latlong:[...]} , ... ];
console.log(a.filter((item) => item.id === 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `filter` which will return an array of objects. Then use index (example `[0]` in this code) to retrieve the first object

```js
var a = [{
  id: 1,
  latlong: ''
}, {
  id: 2,
  latlong: ''
}];

let newVal = a.filter(e => e.id === 2)[0];
console.log(newVal)
```